# Jquery hide div and input by id

Tags: jquery, css

I need to hide a div and 2 input fields, I know how to do this by using the ID and NAME but the code adds a unqiue number to the end of the ID name.  See Below.

```
<div id="gift-messages-for-item-container-295">Gift Message</div>
```

Below is also the INPUT I need to hide, same as before it adds the unique number to the ID and NAME.

```
<input type="text" name="giftmessage[295][from]" id="gift-message-295-from" title="From" value="sadf sadf" class="input-text">
```

If another user loads the page it will change the 295 number.  Does anyone know how I can hide the DIV and INPUT everytime a new number gets added to the end of the ID and NAME?

Cheers

EDIT:

Thanks for all the help, I couldnt get the JQuery working the platform I am using in Magento so I can change the base code.  I have now got it working using CSS.

[id^="gift-messages-for-item-container-"] p {
   display: none;
}
input[name^=giftmessage] {display: none;}

Answer (score 2):

You can do it using jQuery as below,

```
$('[id^="gift-messages-"]').css('display','none');
```

Comment: Hi thanks for response, I have tried it and it doesnt work sadly.

Comment: does DOM are dynamically loaded after page load..?

Comment: Yes I think it does its on a checkout page, after you fill in billing info a box appears for gift message.

Comment: @JohnJones you want to hide it or show it..???

Comment: @JohnJones then this answer would work for u

Answer (score 2):

Add a `class="tohide"` to your element and use the class selector `$('.tohide').hide();`

Answer (score 1):

This will grab the div element and take it's ID and then use that to find the corresponding input element:

```
var identifier = 'gift-messages-for-item-container-';
$div = $('div[id^="' + identifier + '"]');
var id = $div.attr('id').replace(identifier, '');

$div.hide();
$('input[name="giftmessage\[' + id + '\]\[from\]"]').hide();
```

[**Here's an example fiddle.**](http://jsfiddle.net/6z5dT/)

**Note:** I would personally think about adding classes to the input boxes from within your code, to simplify the process.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this -

```
$('div[id^="gift-messages-for-item-container"]').hide();
```

You can select input with name or ID like this -

```
$('input[name^="giftmessage"]').css('display','none');
$('input[id^="gift-message"]').css('display','none');
```

Answer (score 0):

Using css:

```
[id^="gift-messages-"]{
   display: none;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('input[id^="gift"]').hide();

$('div[id^="gift"]').hide();
```

[JS FIDDLE LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/XBkYu/1/)

Comment: take care of code formatting and link  . Now i have edited your answer for these formatting issues .

Comment: thank u rahularyansharma